# What took so long for the implementation of Span<T> and Memory<T>?

Tags: c#-7.2

After learning these new representations of contiguous memory in c# , it looks to me as if this is how it must have been from the beginning. What is the underlying technology that has changed now facilitating these additions now or these were just missed in the initial design of the language

Comment: It is ugly and a compromise for the way it should have been done.  They could not get the CLR team to support slices.  Having to make the distinction between Span and Memory is painful.  The compiler errors when it isn't used correctly are hard to interpret.  The usage of Unsafe in the implementation is risky, we can only hope that they tested all the corner-cases.